# Correct response code for wrong request type

Tags: ajax, http

Which http response code best notifies a user that an api only ajax and post are accepted?

For example i have a controller that will only allow ajax requests and these must be post and not get.

So if an end user was to request using get or post using non ajax they should get a response to indicate this is not allowed.

Would either of these be the best response for this:

400
403
405

Comment: `405` for non-POSTs, `412` if you can detect it's not 'ajaxy', however you plan to detect that....

Comment: im not sure about 412 - i have a feeling that has a very specific use but i cant remember exactly what that was

Answer (score 1):

400 - Bad Request, 405 - Method not allowed

**I think yours is 405**, 403 is forbidden, regarding access permissions, not format or method. Bad Request could be a combination of forbidden parameters

Comment: 400 for non ajax and 405 for non post?

Comment: 405 for non post, no doubt in this. 400 or 405 for non ajax, I would actually go for 405 but maybe both fit the situation

Answer (score 1):

HTTP doesn't have status code to distinguish between requests initiated by XmlHttpRequest (you call it AJAX) and requests made by any other HTTP client or directly by browser.

I guess that by non-ajax request you mean request that is made directly by putting an URL into browser (or by click on a link). It means that browser performs GET request.

**HTTP allows you specify set of allowed HTTP methods for particular resource.**

To fulfill your use-case you just need status code which allows you specify that just POST method is allowed.

**405 - Method not allowed**

> The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the
>   resource identified by the Request-URI. The response MUST include an
>   Allow header containing a list of valid methods for the requested
>   resource.
>   http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.6

Practically it means that your server will return 405 for GET,PUT,DELETE methods.